# Multiple Html <head> in the browser , caused by DreamWeaver bom 

Tags: html, safari, xhtml-1.0-strict

I am using DreamWeaver to code xHtml docs. in the program the code is valid but when I upload it in the inspect element I see double <head> tags and when I right-click to see the source file it seems o.k.

Is it because I'm using dreamweaver? what can be wrong?
the first error is : "Extra <html> encountered.  Migrating attributes back to the original <html> element and ignoring the tag." - in line 3

The code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="keywords" content="the content of my doc" />
<meta name="description" content="this is an example document" />
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="rss feeds" href="linkto/xml/feeds.xml" />
<!-- scripts -->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<title>The Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<!-- content -->
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: I don't know what "in the program the code is valid" means. Have you pasted the actual source into validator.w3.org?

Comment: I cannot see what the error is, but you **should** have a `title` element in your head: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.4.2

Comment: its a function in dreamweaver that checks for compatibility i think.

Comment: Where exactly do you see duplicate head tags? Have you run the code through the validator?

Comment: @Pekka: I guess she sees it in Safari, when checking the uploaded file using Developer Tools. I suspect the DOM being built twice.

Comment: In which version of Safari does this problem show up? And: Mac or Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No problem in Chromium 5.0.307.9 (Developer Build 39052) under Linux. I can't test it in Safari now.

**EDIT:** Proposed test case had nothing to do with this problem, neither could see any extra `<head>` tags. However, I looked at the Developer Tools of Safari and Chrome under Windows and Firebug in Firefox and all three rendered the DOM incorrectly. Just have a look at [**this picture**](http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4021/4397103458_dcda112d64_o.png) and see that the first `<link>` tag has jumped into the body.

This problem also has nothing to do with Javascript because when turning off Javascript the result is [**the same**](http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4060/4397103508_84b87e222a_o.png), even more clear when comparing with the source code. Strange I didn't notice this under Linux.

The Developer Tools of the WebKit browsers give an [**even clearer picture**](http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4008/4396336907_19542ac236_o.png) (also notice the jQuery error message). I suspect the [**Unicode Byte-Order Mark (BOM)**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) at the beginning of the file causing the problem: as you can see the BOM is moved to the `<body>` of the document, perhaps dragging several elements in the `<head>` with it. But also the unclosed `<link>` elements, [**as shown by the W3C validator**](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.tsuriellaw.com), might give some issues, although browsers usually handle this without any problems. First get rid of the BOM in your file and see if the problem persists.

And I see another error: those tags beginning with `<meta ...` are called meta tags, not "meat tags". ;-)

Comment: I think the problem is with the Twitter widget. I see some extra code in the head (with closing tag) and that is what makes the problem.

I think I should not use twitter widget and make my own code.

Comment: @Sophia: That could be the case, as the validator doesn't process Javascript. Is the Twitter widget put in its own `iframe`?

Comment: no, I just place the script in it's own div. 
I see the double head tags in the Safari developer tool, and I am sure that the extra code is from the twitter widget. I think that it is somehow added a closing tag to the head. it added extra scripts and links to css style-sheets to the head (I mean it added the code when it's online).

Comment: @Sophia: Yes, I see, I just put that script in jsbeautifier.org and it puts something in the head three times. I don't get this problem in Chromium, so I will test your page in Safari under Windows later this evening. In the mean time, look at http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://www.tsuriellaw.com (nothing really serious there, but those errors could cause some unexpected problems, especially the Byte-Order Mark. Also, note "document type does not allow element "script" here; assuming missing "li" start-tag").

Comment: I'm tried to get rid from the BOM in my doc. since I'm using Dreamweaver I change the preferences not to use the BOM. 

I even made a new file and copy-paste the content but it still appears with the BOM. maybe when I copy the older content to the new file it also copy the BOM? 

I google about how to get rid from the BOM in Dreamweaver and I think that the changes can made for new files. 

Should I re-write the file in this case?

Comment: @Sophia: I'm sorry, I really don't know Dreamweaver and I have no access to it, so I can't figure this out for you. The only thing I can recommend is: use a nice text editor (good ones support syntax highlighting and the like) and delete the BOM manually. I imagine Dreamweaver includes an option to view and edit the HTML source as well.

Comment: I'm using Dreamweaver in code mode, 
Thank you very much you helped mw a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a title element what you write between
the `<title></title>` tags will been displayed in top bar of your browser

Comment: Sorry, I meant it is valid in Dreamweaver. now I tested it trough validator.w3.org and it doesn't report about double head tags.

by checking it trough the Safari developer I see double head tags

Comment: @Sophia: can you post (a link to) your source code? That makes it a lot easier to see what could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure your

```
</head>
```

tag has *the slash* in the actual file you're working on. That's an easy typo.

Answer (score 0):

To remove BOM from your document, you can use this php function:

```
function removeBOM($str=""){
    if(substr($str, 0,3) == pack("CCC",0xef,0xbb,0xbf)) {
            $str=substr($str, 3);
    }
    return $str;}
```